# Create a record OutOfOffice

Tags: apex, permissions

When I try to create a OutOfOffice record with which the other user is not my own user in apex, Salesforce throw the DML error ("INVALID_ACCESS_LEVEL, Only Self User can update the Out Of Office Message").
Only throw this error if the Profile user isn´t System Administrator.

The class is without sharing.

```
public without sharing class OutOfOfficeHelper {
```

This is the class:

```
public static void set(Id userId, String message, String sStartDate, String sEndDate) {
    DateTime startDate = DateTime.ValueofGmt(sStartDate.replace('T', ' ')); 
    DateTime endDate = DateTime.ValueofGmt(sEndDate.replace('T', ' ')); 

    // extract existing record
    Id outOfOfficeId;
    for(OutOfOffice o: [SELECT Id FROM OutOfOffice WHERE UserId = :userId]) {
        outOfOfficeId = o.Id;
    }
    upsert new OutOfOffice(
        Id = outOfOfficeId,
        UserId = userId,
        IsEnabled = true,
        StartDate=startDate,
        EndDate=endDate,
        message=message);
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can not update UserId field on OutOfOffice object. You can only - (Create, Filter, Group, Sort) the UserId of OutOfOffice object.

Refer here:- [OutOfOffice Soap Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_outofoffice.htm)

> As a workround, You can delete the OutOfOffice record and create a new
>   one with the new userid.

Also, Users can set only their own out-of-office message. An admin can set an out-of-office message for any user.